# C# Exception Include Event Details

Tags: c#, windows, exception

I am new to C# and Windows development in general. I need to use it to build an integration between our data in MySQL to Microsoft Dynamics GP (using eConnect). That part is not really relevant, but adds a little context to the examples below.

Ok, so when I connect to the service:

```
eConnectClient client = new eConnectClient();
string newCustomerDocument = "SOME_XML_HERE";
string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=GPVPM;";
try
{
    client.Open();
    bool result = client.CreateEntity(connectionString, newCustomerDocument);
}
catch (FaultException<eConnectFault> e)
{ 
    Console.Write("ECONNECT FAULT: " + e.ToString() + "\n");
}
```

Now, if I have an error in my XML, it will cause a `FaultException` to be thrown, but the resulting exception message is useless:

> ECONNECT FAULT: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[GPConnect.eConnect.eConnectFault]: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason. (Fault Detail is equal to GPConnect.eConnect.eConnectFault).

I found that if I look in the **Event Viewer** for Windows, it paints an entirely different picture of what happened:

[image]

Specifically:

> Error Number = 250  Stored Procedure= taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd  Error Description = The Tax Schedule does not exist in the Tax Schedule Master Table

So that is something actionable that can help me identify the problem and fix it.

**The question:**

With C#, how can I get the same level of details from an Exception as is recorded by the Event Manager?

Comment: Try to debug your application and inspect the thrown exception in the debugger, perhaps the information is there. Of what specific type is the exception?

Comment: Have you checked that the information is not kept inside the InnerException property?

Comment: It is a `FaultException<eConnectFault>`. I've tried checking various other properties like the InnerException and the Data, but they are empty as well.

Comment: Cillosis, I am dynamics GP developer and now just started learning C#. Could I interact with you in future if needed to discuss things on sample topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server may and may not return the detailed exception to the client. You may want to check

```
e.Detail /* of type GPConnect.eConnect.eConnectFault */
```

and

```
e.InnerException
```

inside the catch block for potential details.

Comment: That's what I basically meant with my comment above.

Comment: Haha, somehow I never noticed the `Detail` property. I just output `e.Detail.Message` and it has everything that I need! Thanks! Will accept answer soon as the option is available.